# Can someone help translate this Trumas HaDeshen?

Tags: shabbat, yom-tov, politics-government

I am looking for any sources that give a reason why we should stay away from politics on shabbos or yomtov. I found [this from the Trumas HaDeshen 61](https://www.torahmusings.com/2019/02/texts-talking-politics-on-shabbos/), but I am having a tough time understanding. Would someone be able to translate it for me?

Here it is on Sefaria: https://www.sefaria.org/Terumat_HaDeshen%2C_Part_I.61?lang=bi

> אמנם ראיתי הרבה פעמים שמקצת מאותם בני אדם המתאספים לספר שמועות הללו אינם מתענגים בריבוי שמועות הללו אלא שעושים כן לרצון חבריהם הנאספים עמהן כה"ג נראה דיש חשש איסור לאותן שאין מתענגים

[image: Screenshot of Terumas HaDeshen]

Answer (score 5):

"However, I have seen many times that some of the people who gather together to discuss these things don't enjoy the long talks about it, they are just doing it to please their friends who are gathered with them. In such a case it would seem that there would be a concern of Issur for those who don't enjoy it."

What he is saying is as follows: The Gemara in [Shabbos 113a-b](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.113b.1?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) writes

> ״ודבר דבר״ —
> שלא יהא דבורך של שבת כדבורך של חול.
>
> (Isaiah 58:13) - “And speaking idle words” - that your speech on Shabbat should not be like your speech during the week, i.e., one should not discuss his weekday affairs on Shabbat.

[Tosfos](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.113b.1?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi&p2=Tosafot_on_Shabbat.113b.1.1&lang2=bi) and the Rosh there explain this Gemara based on Vayikra Rabbah 34 to mean that one can't engage in any idle chatter on Shabbos (as opposed to [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.113b.1?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Shabbat.113b.1.1&lang2=bi) who understands that only talking about business is forbidden).

Furthermore, the [Yerushalmi in Shabbos 78b](https://www.sefaria.org/Jerusalem_Talmud_Shabbat.78b.1?vhe=Mechon_Mamre_Talmud_Yerushalmi&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) says that it was only with difficulty that they permitted one to greet another person on Shabbos.

However, the Terumas Hadeshen there brings that its Mutar to talk about these things if you personally enjoy it. However, if one doesn't enjoy it and is merely talking about it because their friends enjoy it, that would be forbidden.

Comment: Does he give any insight as to what the issur would be?

Comment: What about all the zmiros that say to stay away from it. Besides, I'd think it's assur due to mimtzo cheftzecha

Comment: @Dov I explained.